# How to multiply two values assign to text?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to multiply `ColumnD` with `ColumnE`.

`ColumnD` possible values are : `High, Medium, Low`.

`ColumnE` possible values are : `High, Medium, Low`.

```
High = 3
Medium = 2
Low = 1
```

`ColumnF` is the result of `ColumnD * ColumnE`. For example `High * Medium = 6`.

So, `ColumnF` values are `1 or 2 or ... or 9`.

```
1 to 3 = Low
4 to 6 = Medium
7 to 9 = Low
```

Value displayed on `ColumnF` must be the text value and not the numeric one.

There is a way to do that please ?

Thank you.

**Update 1**

```
 ColumnD | ColumnE | ColumnF | ColumnG | Column H | ColumnI 
 High    | Low     |         |         | Low      | 1
                                       | Medium   | 2
                                       | High     | 3
                                       | Low      | 1
                                       | Low      | 2
                                       | Low      | 3
                                       | Medium   | 4
                                       | Medium   | 5
                                       | Medium   | 6
                                       | High     | 7
                                       | High     | 8
                                       | High     | 9
```

Comment: Hi, what have you tried and where have you gotten stuck?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I have defined a corresponding map but I don't know what is used on Excel to make the correspondence. I already try with `LOOKUP`.

Comment: Have you tried `if` in a formula or vba?

Comment: With a `if` and values put in the `if` it will work, however I need something to get automaticaly from corresponding map.

Comment: Your picture is confusing. How can they take different values?

Comment: Indeed I fix the error (different values because it is a multiplication).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in column D to E as per your question, and your references in H to I as per your table, you could try the following formula in column F.

```
=INDEX($H$4:$H$12,INDEX($H$1:$I$3,MATCH(D1,$H$1:$H$3,0),2)*INDEX($H$1:$I$3,MATCH(E1,$H$1:$H$3,0),2),1)
```

This will index the first three rows of your lookup table, and get the corresponding value for each row from one column over. It does this for both your values, and multiplies them. With the result, this is returned to a `INDEX(` statement as a row number, and will return whichever value is on that row on the second part of your lookup table. This makes having numbers next to the second part of your table redundant.

Comment: Thank you a lot. However, when I replaced with my values I'm getting error but `0`. Any idea? `=INDEX($K$9:$K$17;INDEX($K$3:$L$5;MATCH(D5;$K$3:$K$5;0);2)*INDEX($K$6:$L$8;MATCH(E5;$K$6:$K$8;0);2);1)`

Comment: If I use your command in a sheet with same data as in the question, I'm getting `0` also.

Comment: If you get 0, it means any of the values (originals or ones looked up) might be out of range for the scope of the formula. Or the spelling of your data isn't identical to your lookup values, or it might be stored as something other than text (unlikely).

Comment: Oh it was because I merged some cells on the corresponding map. Thank you a lot it is a perfect solution.